# Show more products in the admin products page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

Some times I want to list all your products in one page in the products.
By default it only shows 20 items and you need to click the '>' to see the rest products.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to check the 'screen option' in the right corner of the screen in order to view more products or pages. It is very useful in daily task for wordpress admin user.

[image]